# “DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE” on Windows 10

Tags: bsod, windows-10-preview

I've been prompted with BSoD, at seemingly random times, with the above error. This is off a fresh install of Windows 10 (2 times in fact) on a new hard drive. This is my model: https://docs.sony.com/release/specs/SVF15A18CXB_mksp.pdf

Here are the recent .dmp files for your analysis: http://bit.ly/1d2w4gZ

All my drivers are up to date. Thank you for your time and consideration.

Comment: Bit information (32Bit or 64Bit) of Windows would also be required to debug the crashdump. Refer to resources like [this](http://mywindows8.org/install-configure-windbg-windows-10-windows-8-1-windows-7/)

Comment: Microsoft didn't release debug symbols for Build 10130, so we can't debug it. disable the power saving for some devices in device manager

Comment: In Device Manager, I disabled power saving for: Generic USB Hubs, USB Root Hubs, Broadcom Wireless (disabled since I use ethernet with Realtek PCIe) and Bluetooth (which is turned off anyways); in fact none of these are important since I'm always plugged in. Nevertheless, we'll see whether I get any more issues today.

Comment: Regarding debugging, was there anything I needed to do? Or can we not do anything since it's the Windows 10 TP (x64).

Comment: So apparently the BSoDs still ensue. Anyway to look at those .dmps?

Comment: I've asked a contact from Microsoft for help. I'll post again if I hear something.

Comment: It's greatly appreciated; please let me know if you find anything out.

Comment: I performed an Nvidia update today and after about an hour my computer crashed and I got this error. Now, every time I log onto my computer it crashes after about a minute with the same error. I can't even get into the Windows 8 advanced options during boot up before the computer crashes. This is unbelievable, I don't even think I will be able to reset my PC back to factory settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**: So it's a known driver issue with Nvidia on a pre-release OS. Welcome to beta testing. Some people are lowering the frequency of these errors by using an older Nvidia driver (350.12) or the new beta notebook driver 353.17 or reverting to their onboard video driver while waiting for updated drivers. There's not much else you can do.

## Initial suggestion

- Check Sony's site to see if you have the latest BIOS installed

  - Check for corrupt system files by executing the following from a Command Prompt (Admin) and typing in `sfc /scannow`
  - Use MemTest86 to check for faulty RAM

Comment: I've verified the integrity of my system files, my RAM, and have the latest version of the BIOS already installed. Therefore, there is likely another cause for the BSoD.

Comment: Did you check Device Manager to see if you have all the drivers installed? Sometimes just installing an OS from a generic source (generic being plain vanilla Microsoft in this case and not a Sony specific source) leaves many manufacturer's drivers uninstalled. Sony should have a support site with additional drivers required by your computer. Try using the Sony Windows 8 drivers as I assume they haven't published Windows 10 drivers yet. Chipset, bluetooth, video card and other drivers often must be installed from the manufacturer's site after a clean OS install.

Comment: It seems like I have all my drivers installed. I was missing one a few days ago, and found it online at the Sony site and that was fixed. Windows 10 Sony Drivers are not out, but Windows 8 drivers seem to work perfectly fine (Nvidia is already supporting W10). I'll be trying @magicandre1981 method and seeing if it works, for now. Thanks

Comment: So it's a known driver issue with nVidia on a pre-release OS. Welcome to beta testing. Some people are lowering the frequency of these errors by using an older nVidia driver (350.12) or the new beta notebook driver 353.17 or reverting to their onboard video driver while waiting for updated drivers. Not much else you can do...

Comment: @GamersRule: uhm ... what? The bugcheck code is crystal clear. WinDbg proves that `nt` tears down the system, so all points to a misbehaving driver. Nothing even pointed to RAM or hardware in the first place, although BIOS (also for the VGA) is always a possibility. HighTechGeek is spot on, though, `lm` shows nVidia drivers loaded and you would be well advised to check the driver timestamps for those nVidia drivers against the driver bundle (unless you know already). I think that HighTechGeek is **spot on**. And it's on nVidia to fix the issues (i.e. not MS, none of us certainly).  +1 to HTG!

Comment: @0xC0000022L Not sure why there was some confusion. After being told it was caused by a Nvidia Driver, and doing some research, it was about as clear as you make it out to be. This was established a while back. I also know that the two drivers HTG mentioned are lowering the frequency of the issue but not solving it all together. As of right now, I have my nVidia driver uninstalled and am using the integrated graphics with no issues (no intensive games, after all) until a fix rolls out.

Comment: @GamersRule: actually, you won't believe it, I looked at the dump files to establish which drivers are loaded (no symbols needed for that; none needed to see which module was the culprit either). Hadn't even scrolled down to the other question before that point.

Answer (score 1):

My Microsoft contact looked at the dump and told me, that the nVIDIA GPU driver caused it. So [update the nVIDIA driver](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/Find.aspx?lang=en-us) and try the Windows 10 driver, which nVIDIA offers.

On 2015/06/22, nVIDIA relased a [new WHQL driver 353.30](http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/86510/en-us). Try this updated driver.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this! A little bit strange since I'm quite certain I downloaded the latest, proper version for Windows 10 (I have the 735m) from that site. Will give it a shot though.

Comment: In fact, I took a look at what I have right now and it seems correct: http://bit.ly/1MRz2RF - I will try uninstalling/reinstalling it however

Comment: Looking at this, it seems to be an issue with the specific driver: http://bit.ly/1Sv0WXn and http://bit.ly/1JZkXUD

Comment: What would be the best course of action?

Comment: also reply to the topic and wait for a reply of nVIDIA and try newer drivers, if they produce one.

Comment: @GamersRule I added a link to a new nVIDIA driver. Please try this one.

Comment: Thanks, I will try installing it now. Though, feedback for this driver doesn't seem to good.

Comment: @GamersRule there is a new hotfix: http://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3694 try this version.

Comment: Thanks for the update. So far 353.30 has been working surprisingly well (no BSoD yet), but I will definitely try the hotfix.

Answer (score 0):

you can also try [GeForce Hotfix driver 353.38](https://forums.geforce.com/default/topic/849203/geforce-drivers/announcing-geforce-hotfix-driver-353-38/)

Answer (score 0):

I have had this error message on 4 different occasions this past week while working on a system that ultimately got updated to Windows 10 Pro.

i7-3770/16GB with 1TB Crucial SSD and finally a 256GB SSD with an NVIDIA GT630

Each time I got that screen (some are calling a BSOD), is when  was forced to do the hard reset on the computer and then the rather quick restart.  I attributed it to the SSD not being able to fully recover/prepare for a restart.
I validated this, albeit maybe not the reason, by the next time I need to do a forced restart using the switch on the power supply and letting the system rest for a few seconds.  I haven't seen the problem since.

btw. . .system is finally up and running by replacing the 1TB SSD with the 256GB.