# Win_10 Driver_Power_State_Failure

Tags: windows-10, drivers, bsod

I have a *new* **Dell Insprion 7559 i7**, that has been crashing after 2 hours, and I don't understand why this is happening. Here's my [dump file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7wYRMCnmAtVZ25OM0ZOR2lHMms).

**My PC Details:**

- Intel i7 -6700HQ @ 2.60GHz
- 16GB DDR3 RAM
- Windows 10 Home Single Language 64bit
- NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960M
- 1TB Westgate HDD
- SanDisk Z400s M.2 2280 128GB

What is wrong with my PC?

Comment: It sounds like something related to your Graphics Card.  Have you tried the solution in [this](http://superuser.com/questions/929330/driver-power-state-failure-on-windows-10) post?

Comment: It seems to be something with your NVIDIA driver so I would suggest you check their website for an updated driver or known bugs, etc. with the version of driver you're using now. It seems to be related to the NVIDIA regardless based on quick analysis of the latest DMP file you provided so I'd start with that if you can just in case... Let me know how it goes and what you find.

Comment: @PIMP_JUICE_IT Would be okay to just update it or look for more posts on the version(353.82 by the way)?

Comment: Check here the auto detect your GPU and see what it suggested, etc.: http://www.geforce.com/drivers

Comment: @PIMP_JUICE_IT It is a 960M.

Comment: It seems that the 368.81 version is available and release date of July 14, 2016 so I'd go with that much newer version as I'm sure they've patched many bugs, etc. since: http://www.geforce.com/drivers/results/105039  Please give that a shot and see if that resolves the issue. If so, I will be glad to add that as an answer for you but that is exactly what I'd do next since it's confirmed to be an NVIDIA issue with the DMP files you provided. That's the link to the Windows 10 64-bit driver by the way, I assume you're on x64 CPU.

Comment: @TimmyJim I tried that and Windows reports that there are no integrity violations.

Comment: @PIMP_JUICE_IT Alright, will try that now.

Comment: Tony, I just added an answer since I have to step away and I've been working with you on this issue. I hope you find it helpful and worthy of acceptance and an upvote once you confirm.

Comment: @PIMP_JUICE_IT Just a quick note before you jump off, would I just install over or uninstall and then install the driver I downloaded?

Comment: I't been a while since I've installed these drivers on any machines but I think I usually always installed without uninstalling first and it overwrote what it needed but I do not remember 100%. If you're comfortable with uninstalling the older driver package, rebooting the machine, and then reinstalling the new driver package, that would not be a bad idea either. If you install over the top though, check Programs and Features and ensure that only the latest version shows and NOT both. Very good question though for sure... I like the uninstall, reboot, reinstall option though just in case.

Comment: any update? Have you installed v1607 and newer drivers? Does it fix the issues?

Comment: @magicandre1981 I updated to the latest nvidia drivers but that got worse. I then hunted on other forums for info and found out that I need  a Dell driver. I then installed it, but it hasn't changed anything. It just updated Windows as I write(don't know why it took so long). I will post a solution when I find it. For now, still searching... :(  The journey continues...

Comment: So removed ALL the NVIDIA drivers and have a uptime of 2hrs. That's good news at least, but need to find a solution.

Comment: have you made the update to version 1607?

Comment: @magicandre1981 No, I haven't. I've been ''afraid" to use it because of the things that are going wrong with it. I think I'll stay put with what I have. However, I will (soon) call Dell on this issue and (hopefully) have the problem fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After two weeks, my laptop finally works! :)

As pointed by [PIMP_JUICE_IT](https://superuser.com/users/510662/pimp-juice-it) and [magicandre1981](https://superuser.com/users/174557/magicandre1981), there was a problem with my GPU. No drivers could fix the issue(from Dell or NVIDIA). After 4 fresh Windows 10 installations, it was clear that it was a hardware issue (and I called it quits) and phoned Dell. Dell sent a field engineer, and he replaced my motherboard. So it was a hardware issue, and I am relieved it finally works. :D

Thanks @PIMP_JUICE_IT and @magicandre1981 for your initial diagnosis. I learned a lot from this!

Answer (score 3):

According to the crash dump, the nVIDIA driver is from 2015 and your Windows 10 Version 1511 is outdated (older Build 10.0.10586.162 (th2_release_sec.160223-1728)):

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE (9f)
A driver has failed to complete a power IRP within a specific time.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000003, A device object has been blocking an Irp for too long a time
Arg2: ffffe0001da3a060, Physical Device Object of the stack
Arg3: ffffd0017a135890, nt!TRIAGE_9F_POWER on Win7 and higher, otherwise the Functional Device Object of the stack
Arg4: ffffe00021939bd0, The blocked IRP

Debugging Details:
------------------

Implicit thread is now ffffe000`1b6ae040
*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for nvlddmkm.sys
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for nvlddmkm.sys

DUMP_CLASS: 1

DUMP_QUALIFIER: 400

BUILD_VERSION_STRING:  10.0.10586.162 (th2_release_sec.160223-1728)

SYSTEM_MANUFACTURER:  Dell Inc.

SYSTEM_PRODUCT_NAME:  Inspiron 7559

SYSTEM_SKU:  0706

SYSTEM_VERSION:  1.1.8

BIOS_VENDOR:  Dell Inc.

BIOS_VERSION:  1.1.8

BIOS_DATE:  04/17/2016

BASEBOARD_MANUFACTURER:  Dell Inc.

BASEBOARD_PRODUCT:  0H0CC0

BASEBOARD_VERSION:  A00

DUMP_TYPE:  2

BUGCHECK_P1: 3

BUGCHECK_P2: ffffe0001da3a060

BUGCHECK_P3: ffffd0017a135890

BUGCHECK_P4: ffffe00021939bd0

DRVPOWERSTATE_SUBCODE:  3

FAULTING_THREAD:  1b6ae040

CPU_COUNT: 8

CPU_MHZ: a20

CPU_VENDOR:  GenuineIntel

CPU_FAMILY: 6

CPU_MODEL: 5e

CPU_STEPPING: 3

CPU_MICROCODE: 6,5e,3,0 (F,M,S,R)  SIG: 84'00000000 (cache) 84'00000000 (init)

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x9F

PROCESS_NAME:  System

CURRENT_IRQL:  2

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 10.0.14321.1024 amd64fre

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff803233046ca to fffff803233d51f6

STACK_TEXT:  
00 nt!KiSwapContext
01 nt!KiSwapThread
02 nt!KiCommitThreadWait
03 nt!KeWaitForSingleObject
04 nvlddmkm
05 0x0
06 0x0


FOLLOWUP_IP: 
nvlddmkm+1b638f
fffff801`bd11638f ??              ???

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  4

SYMBOL_NAME:  nvlddmkm+1b638f

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: nvlddmkm

IMAGE_NAME:  nvlddmkm.sys

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  55c3eab4

BUCKET_ID_FUNC_OFFSET:  1b638f

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0x9F_3_nvlddmkm!unknown_function

BUCKET_ID:  0x9F_3_nvlddmkm!unknown_function

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  0x9F_3_nvlddmkm!unknown_function

TARGET_TIME:  2016-07-31T20:52:55.000Z

OSBUILD:  10586

OSSERVICEPACK:  162

SERVICEPACK_NUMBER: 0

OS_REVISION: 0

SUITE_MASK:  784

PRODUCT_TYPE:  1

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 10

OSEDITION:  Windows 10 WinNt TerminalServer SingleUserTS Personal

OS_LOCALE:  

USER_LCID:  0

OSBUILD_TIMESTAMP:  2016-02-24 06:48:00

BUILDDATESTAMP_STR:  160223-1728

BUILDLAB_STR:  th2_release_sec

BUILDOSVER_STR:  10.0.10586.162

ANALYSIS_SESSION_ELAPSED_TIME: 223f2

ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  KM

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:0x9f_3_nvlddmkm!unknown_function

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {8b257f08-e34e-7c26-3880-084b82f90c48}

Followup:     MachineOwner
---------

7: kd> !irp ffffe00021939bd0
Irp is active with 6 stacks 5 is current (= 0xffffe00021939dc0)
 No Mdl: No System Buffer: Thread 00000000:  Irp stack trace.  Pending has been returned
     cmd  flg cl Device   File     Completion-Context
 [N/A(0), N/A(0)]
            0  0 00000000 00000000 00000000-00000000    

            Args: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
 [N/A(0), N/A(0)]
            0  0 00000000 00000000 00000000-00000000    

            Args: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
 [N/A(0), N/A(0)]
            0  0 00000000 00000000 00000000-00000000    

            Args: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
 [IRP_MJ_POWER(16), IRP_MN_WAIT_WAKE(0)]
            0  0 ffffe0001da3a060 00000000 fffff801bad9d5b0-ffffd00179dfd7e0    
           \Driver\pci  dxgkrnl!DpiFdoPowerCompletionRoutine
            Args: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>[IRP_MJ_POWER(16), IRP_MN_SET_POWER(2)]
            0 e1 ffffe000206f2040 00000000 fffff8032339e0b8-ffffe00024befea8 Success Error Cancel pending
           \Driver\nvlddmkm nt!PopRequestCompletion
            Args: 00000000 00000001 00000001 00000000
 [N/A(0), N/A(0)]
            0  0 00000000 00000000 00000000-ffffe00024befea8    

            Args: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
7: kd> !podev ffffe0001da3a060
Device object is for:
  DriverObject 1da41880
Current Irp 00000000 RefCount 0 Type 00000023 AttachedDev ffffe0001da3ae40 DevFlags 00001040
Device queue is not busy.
Device Object Extension: ffffe0001da3a7b0:
PowerFlags: 00000010 =>SystemState=0 DeviceState=1
Dope: 00000000:
7: kd> !devstack ffffe0001da3ae40
  !DevObj           !DrvObj            !DevExt           ObjectName
  ffffe000206f2040  \Driver\nvlddmkm   ffffe000206f2190  InfoMask field not found for _OBJECT_HEADER at ffffe000206f2010

> ffffe0001da3ae40  \Driver\ACPI       ffffe0001bbd5490  
  ffffe0001da3a060  \Driver\pci        ffffe0001da3a1b0  Cannot read info offset from nt!ObpInfoMaskToOffset

!DevNode ffffe0001da3ab30 :
  DeviceInst is "PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_139B&SUBSYS_07061028&REV_A2\4&21e2365b&0&0009"
  ServiceName is "nvlddmkm"
7: kd> lmvm nvlddmkm
Browse full module list
start             end                 module name
fffff801`bcf60000 fffff801`bda48000   nvlddmkm T (no symbols)           
    Loaded symbol image file: nvlddmkm.sys
    Image path: \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\nvlddmkm.sys
    Image name: nvlddmkm.sys
    Timestamp:        Fri Aug  7 01:16:04 2015
```

So, install the [latest nVIDIA driver](http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/105039/en-us) and the latest Update for Version 1511 or update tomorrow to version 1607.

Answer (score 2):

Based on quick analysis of the latest DMP file you provided it seems to be related to something with your NVIDIA driver:

> <sup>FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x9F_3_nvlddmkm_IMAGE_pci.sys</sup>
>
> <sup>BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x9F_3_nvlddmkm_IMAGE_pci.sys</sup>

Based on the [NVIDIA website results when searching for the latest driver for Windows 10 x64](http://www.geforce.com/drivers/results/105039), version ***368.81*** is available for download which is much newer than your current driver version of ***353.82*** so many bugs, etc. have certainly been patched since the version you're running.

I would suggest for you to download the [NVIDIA 368.81 Driver](http://www.geforce.com/drivers/results/105039) and install it for the next step and see if that resolves the problem you're experiencing that the NVIDIA 353.82 driver seems to cause.

> ### [GEFORCE Drivers](http://www.geforce.com/drivers)
>
> **Version:**  368.81 - WHQL
>
> **Release Date:** Thu Jul 14, 2016
>
> **Operating System:** Windows 10 64-bit
>
> **Language:** English (US)
>
> **File Size:**    343.87 MB
>
> <sub>[source](http://www.geforce.com/drivers/results/105039)</sub>